# Dynamic Column Name In Cursor PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I've been working on a query in pl/sql. I've almost same named columns like **column1, column2, column3**.

In Cursor, how can i get value of these columns using dynamically name.
For example:

```
FOR Cursor_r IN Cursor_c LOOP
    BEGIN 

        IF Cursor_r.column1 = 'dummy1' THEN 
             MyProc(Cursor_r.column1);
        ELSIF Cursor_r.column1 = 'dummy2' THEN
             MyProc(Cursor_r.column2);
        ELSIF Cursor_r.column1 = 'dummy3' THEN
             MyProc(Cursor_r.column3);
        END IF;

    END; 
END LOOP;
```

Thanks.

Comment: provide the sample query you have tried..

Comment: No, you can't. The column name must be static.

Comment: Hi, I showed my query now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamical sql to get all column names. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i1027597)